# How can I enable debug mode in a dpdk-based application?

Tags: c, debugging, logging, network-programming, dpdk

I encounter some errors when running a dpdk-based application. I find the error occurs when invoking `rte_eth_dev_configure()` function provided by dpdk library. The error code is -22. However, I want the application to show more debug information so that I can quickly focus on the error part.

I did RTFM and modified `$RTE_SDK/build/.config`. I turned `RTE_LIBRTE_ETHDEV_DEBUG` to be `y`. But It didn't work. Where does `rte_vlog()` function put log messages?

Would you like to help me? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also change the default log level, otherwise all the debug messages will be compiled out during the compilation, i.e.:

```
RTE_LOG_LEVEL=RTE_LOG_DEBUG
RTE_LIBRTE_ETHDEV_DEBUG=y
```

Please also have a look at `EXTRA_CFLAGS`. You might also want to add the debug symbols and disable optimizations, i.e.:

```
make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-O0 -g" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I add `CONFIG_ RTE_LIBRTE_ETHDEV_DEBUG=y` to the `${RTE_SDK}/config/defconfig_{RTE_TARGET}` config file and rebuild the target. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of DPDK have the following debug mechanisms:

### Per component debug logging

Pass `"--log-level=lib.eal:debug"` parameter to `rte_eal_init()`, see https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_eal_parameters.html

### Dataplane debug logging

In `config/rte_config.h` replace

```
#define RTE_LOG_DP_LEVEL RTE_LOG_INFO
```

with

```
#define RTE_LOG_DP_LEVEL RTE_LOG_DEBUG
```

### Debug data checks and other dataplane logs

Add `-DRTE_LIBRTE_ETHDEV_DEBUG` to the build.