# DPDK run testpmd failed. EAL:no probed ethernet device

Tags: dpdk

I'm new to dpdk and using dpdk-stable-17.11.2 on docker.
OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and the kernel is 3.19.0-80-generic.
I've followed the dpdk-setup.sh as below and bind the igb_uio driver to my device.

```
[14] x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
[17] Insert IGB UIO module
[18] Insert VFIO module
[19] Insert KNI module
[20] Setup hugepage mappings for non-NUMA systems
[21] Setup hugepage mappings for NUMA systems
[22] Display current Ethernet/Crypto device settings
[23] Bind Ethernet/Crypto device to IGB UIO module
[24] Bind Ethernet/Crypto device to VFIO module
[25] Setup VFIO permissions
```

---

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:03:00.1 'NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet 168e' drv=igb_uio unused=vfio-pci

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:03:00.0 'NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet 168e' if=eth1 drv=bnx2x unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci *Active*
0000:04:00.0 'NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express 1677' if=eth0 drv=tg3 unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci *Active*
0000:07:00.0 'NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter 0100' if=eth3 drv=netxen_nic unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci
0000:07:00.1 'NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter 0100' if=eth4 drv=netxen_nic unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci
```

---

I got errors when running testpmd.

```
EAL: Detected 32 lcore(s)
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: No probed ethernet devices
PANIC in main():
Empty set of forwarding logical cores - check the core mask supplied in the command parameters
5: [x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app/testpmd() [0x46504f]]
4: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fe9117c9f45]]
3: [x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app/testpmd(main+0x8fb) [0x460aab]]
2: [x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app/testpmd(__rte_panic+0xb8) [0x458a7a]]
1: [x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app/testpmd(rte_dump_stack+0x1a) [0x4ea2aa]]
```

What have I missed?

Comment: What's the command you used to run testpmd?

Comment: I tried it from the dpdk-setup.sh  
`./testpmd -c 0x01 -n 4 -- -i`

Comment: Could you try with `./testpmd -l 0 -c 0x01 -n 4 -- -i`?

Comment: Seems that it doesn't accept two options together.`EAL: Option -c is ignored, because (-l) is set!`

Comment: Oh, right! I though `-c` was the number of channels; my bad. That command looks alright.
Since you're running DPDK inside a container, did you run all of the above (dpdk installation, NIC driver binding, and testpmd) inside the container? Is the container privileged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_BNX2X_PMD=n` to `CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_BNX2X_PMD=y` in the $RTE_SDK/config/common_base.

> 0000:03:00.1 'NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet 168e' drv=igb_uio unused=vfio-pci
>   [...]
>   EAL: No probed ethernet devices

This error has solved.

Answer (score 0):

> 0000:03:00.1 'NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet 168e' drv=igb_uio unused=vfio-pci
>   [...]
>   EAL: No probed ethernet devices

BCM57810 seems to be unsupported by the current version of Broadcom PMD:
https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/bnxt.html

As a workaround you can try to use a supported NIC instead (if possible) or a virtual device (might be much slower).

> PANIC in main():
>   Empty set of forwarding logical cores - check the core mask supplied in the command parameters

You did not list the your command line options, but you definitely should check it for a lcore mask or core list or core map. Here is the list of EAL command line options:
https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html

Comment: Hi @Andriy Berestovskyy,  

Since my original driver for BCM57810 is bnx2x, I checked the supported PCI device:  

http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/drivers/net/bnx2x/bnx2x_ethdev.c#n27  

https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/bnx2x.html  

I thought that it should support?  

Also, the command I run testpmd is  
`./testpmd -c 0x01 -n 4 -- -i  `

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @yhwu regarding the NIC. Try to [enable debug logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790009/7969900). Regarding the core mask. There is no need to put 0x at the beginning, just `-c 1` should work.