# testpmd: No probed ethernet devices message

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to use DPDK 19.11 in centOS 8.0. I have compiled DPDK as per guidelines. Then I did bind ethernet NIC to DPDK driver and left Wifi to Linux kernel using dpdk_setup.sh.

1.When I try to use testpmd the following message is displayed.
"testpmd: No probed ethernet devices" though the port is bounded.

When I try to use dpdk_pdump, I get the message
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
Cause: No Ethernet ports - bye

Please find driver allocation

Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver

0000:03:00.0 'RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 8168' drv=igb_uio unused=r8169

Network devices using kernel driver

0000:02:00.0 'Wireless 3160 08b4' if=wlp2s0 drv=iwlwifi unused=igb_uio *Active*

Executed testpmd and dpdkpdump from the following folders
/home/vijay/fwldpdk/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/app

testpmd output

$ sudo ./testpmd -c f -n 4 -- -i

EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)

EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes

EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket

EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'

EAL: Probing VFIO support...

testpmd: No probed ethernet devices

Interactive-mode selected

testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mbuf_pool_socket_0>: n=171456, size=2176, socket=0

testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc

Done

testpmd> show port

Bad arguments

testpmd> show port 0

Bad arguments

testpmd> show port 1

Bad arguments

DPDK_pdump output

$ sudo ./dpdk-pdump

EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)

EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes

EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket_75341_87718f3ca82

EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'

EAL: Probing VFIO support...

EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1

Cause: No Ethernet ports - bye

I did refer the following question
[DPDK run testpmd failed. EAL:no probed ethernet device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522124/dpdk-run-testpmd-failed-ealno-probed-ethernet-device).

2.If I put wifi interface also to DPDK driver whether testpmd will forward packets between two DPDK ports?

3. We bring down NIC interface so that it can be bounded to DPDK driver. Do we need to bring it up once it's attached with DPDK using any command?

Any inputs on how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation of Having RTL and Wifi are incorrect. List of supported DPDK [ports](http://core.dpdk.org/supported/).

Comment: Just wanted to know is that the main reason, I was not able to test DPDK in my laptop and guest VM where host machine is having port that is not supported by DPDK. I failed to notice that.